# Firebase Firestore Codable is nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift5, codable

I have this model and I want to fetch results from Firebase Firestore.

```
struct Notification: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var type: String
    var createdAt: Date
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case type
        case createdAt //Firestore Timestamp
      }
}
```

ViewModel

```
    self.notifications = snapshot.documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Notification? in
        print(try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Notification.self)) //nil
        return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Notification.self)
    }
```

The problem is that the model is nil when I try to fill an array.

[image]

I have tried it also without the `createdAt` (timestamp) and still it fails.

Anything wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `createdAt` property of your Notification object is a Date and what's stored in Firestore is a Timestamp

```
struct Notification: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var type: String
    var createdAt: Date <- needs to be a Timestamp
```

You can either change the property to match, or convert the Firestore Timestamp to a date

```
let aDate = timestamp.dateValue()
```

If you want to use the Date property you can include an init in the struct to handle that

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
   let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
   self.type = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
   let ts = try values.decode(TimeStamp.self, forKey: .createdAt)
   self.myDate = ts.dateValue()
```

Comment: How do I convert the timestamp to a Date ? In the Decodable?

Comment: also there is another issue because even without the createdAt it is still nil

Comment: @Rexhin To answer the first comment/question, one design pattern is to include an init in your struct to handle the decoding. Let me put a quick example in the answer. Also, the code in your question works with test data so the issue with it being nil lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Rexhin I copy and pasted your code into a project and it successfully read in the notification objects and correctly decoded them into an array.